# antd dropdown : selected value displaying outside the select

Tags: reactjs, antd

I my code I am using ant Design (antd). In my drop down list I am using `<span>` tag to dispaly my listings as two columns.

```
<Select value={'AccountID'} style={{'width':'212px','height':'32px'}}  placeholder="Select An Accounts">
                    <Option disabled value='0'>Select An Account</Option>
                        {this.props.accountList.length && this.props.accountList.map((value,index)=>(
                          <Option  value={value.AccountID} key={index}>
                           {value.Name} <span style={{float:'right'}}> {value.TypeName} </span>
                          </Option>
                        ))}
                    </Select>
```

[image]

The problem is when I select a long option like *Freight and Shipping Costs*
, after selecting *CostOfGoodsSold* is displayed outside the conttrol as shown below.
[image]

As an alternate solution,

If I increase the with of the select tag:-

there is no space showing between the two values after selection. I need space between values.[image]

How to overcome this issue?
PS: any other CSS not applied.
Demo: [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/m268vxq3x)

Comment: Can you create demo to reproduce this issue?

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/m268vxq3x
This is when the width of the select increased @Just code
When width is changed to `200 px` the first problem arises

Comment: What is your expected behaviour?

Comment: * If I use a `200px` select, I dont want to display the 2nd value below the select control
* If I use `400px` select, after selecting a value from the drop down list I need tho show space between them as same as in the drop down list

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As per your requirement I would like to use percentage to resolve your issue,

there is one property called `dropdownStyle` in antd which you can use to design the options of the dropdown.

so, by applying

```
 dropdownStyle={{ minWidth: "50%", height: "32px" }}
```

You should be able to get the options added.

Here is what your select looks like

```
<Select
    placeholder="Select An Account"
    dropdownStyle={{ minWidth: "50%", height: "32px" }}
    style={{ minWidth: "50%", height: "32px" }}
  >
    <Option value="1">
      Freight and Shipping Cost
      <span style={{ float: "right" }}> Cost of Goods Sold</span>
    </Option>
    <Option value="2">
      Sales
      <span style={{ float: "right" }}> Income</span>
    </Option>
  </Select>
```

after selecting the dropdown there is no property I can find to overwrite so you need to apply css to that. for selected item.

```
.ant-select-selection-selected-value {
  width: 100%;
}
```

[Demo of sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/2voy8k9rxn)

Comment: @JaneFred it is already showing spaces in between check my demo

Comment: I have added css for that `.ant-select-selection-selected-value {
  width: 100%;
}` its working as expected

Comment: When I applied this the structure of the dropdown list chenged.
If you both of our sandbox codes you can find it

Comment: @JaneFred give a link

Comment: codesandbox.io/s/m268vxq3x   Mine(old).

https://codesandbox.io/s/2voy8k9rxn Yours.

Just look the slight variation of structure after clicking on the select

Comment: @JaneFred its a space which I added, https://codesandbox.io/s/2voy8k9rxn I removed now