# antd optionRender (5.11.0) justify description to the right side

Tags: reactjs, antd

With antd 5.11.0 there was a `optionRender` prop introduced for the Select component: https://ant.design/components/select

I want to display an icon as well as the option's label on the left side and the description on the right side, but everything is justified on the left side.

```
    optionRender={(option) => (
      <Space style={{justifyContent: 'space-between'}}>
        <Space style={{justifyContent: 'start'}}>{ option.data.desc=='tag' ? <TagOutlined style={{color: 'red'}}/> : (option.data.dataType=='string' ? <FieldStringOutlined style={{color: '#13c2c2'}}/> : (option.data.dataType=='boolean' ? <FieldBinaryOutlined style={{color: '#13c2c2'}}/> :  (option.data.dataType=='numeric' ? <FieldNumberOutlined style={{color: '#13c2c2'}}/> : <FieldTimeOutlined style={{color: '#13c2c2'}}/> ))) }
        {option.data.label}</Space>
        <Space style={{justifyContent: 'end'}}>{option.data.desc}</Space>
      </Space>
    )}
```

I also tried `float: 'right'` that was described here https://stackoverflow.com/a/53994006/14227630 , though for the older `dropdownStyle` prop.
Thank you for any help!

Comment: Pass `display: flex` in first Space style obhect

Answer (score 0):

*antd 5.14.2*.

Adding the `display: 'flex';` to the outer `<Space/>` component.

```
import { Select, Space } from 'antd';
import { TagOutlined } from '@ant-design/icons';

export const App = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <Select
        options={[
          {
            label: 'USA',
            value: 'usa',
            desc: 'USA (美国)',
          },
          {
            label: 'Japan',
            value: 'japan',
            desc: 'Japan (日本)',
          },
          {
            label: 'Korea',
            value: 'korea',
            desc: 'Korea (韩国)',
          },
        ]}
        defaultValue="usa"
        style={{ width: 200 }}
        optionRender={(option) => (
          <Space style={{ display: 'flex', justifyContent: 'space-between' }}>
            <Space>
              <TagOutlined style={{ color: 'red' }} />
              {option.data.label}
            </Space>
            {option.data.desc}
          </Space>
        )}
      />
    </div>
  );
};
```

Output:

[image]

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-feubbv?file=src%2FApp.tsx)